# Remove hakintosh and reinstall XP

Tags: macos, windows-xp, formatting

I've installed Hackintosh on my Esprimo mobile V5505, and it worked well.

Now I would like to format my HD and reinstall XP. If I run windows XP installation CD, the C drive is not shown. Entering in the windows recovery console and running the CHKDSK command, it returns unrecoverable errors on disk C. But if I restart all without the cd inserted, Hackintosh starts without problems. How can I remove it and reinstall Windows XP? Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your BIOS Sata controller is set to AHCI mode. Try changing it to ATA mode.This should be the issue.

Comment: After installation download and install AHCI driver. Then re enable AHCI mode. Otherwise it may affect performance in WIndows 8 or 7, if you are planning to install one. If you face any issue check this link http://www.blah-blah.ch/it/how-to-s/enable-ahci/

Answer (score 0):

It might be because Mac usually uses the HFS or HFS+ format, it might need to be formatted to FAT32 or NTFS prior to the install of windows being able to recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Destroy the partition using some sort of tool like FDISK or gparted.

Comment: I deleted the ntfs partition I found with gparted and run again the windows XP install cd, but again, it can't see any disk. Also trying to format in fat32, I can't find any partition from XP CD. I'm really confused about this...